# The departing: Gerunds and more

Tags: verb, verb-usage, gerund

How would I translate "the Departing" in German?

As in "You all, the Departing, give up all hope!"

I doubt "Departing" in this context is a gerund, so how would I translate this verb-turned-into-a-noun?

Comment: You may get better answers if you gave us more context, thank you.

Comment: Maybe "Ihr, die Scheidenden - gebt alle Hoffnung auf!" (present participle used as a noun by adding -e/-er/-en depending on case, gender and article)

Comment: Another possibility: "Ihr, die ihr fortgeht - lasst alle Hoffnung fahren." (which you'll only encounter in ancient texts)

Comment: "Ihr, die ihr uns verlasst, ..." - this would avoid assuming they are literally going. Similar to "die Scheidenden" in that sense, but doesn't sound so uncommon. Btw, the original from Dante's Inferno is "Abandon hope all ye who enter here"

Answer (score 1):

As no-one came up with a better idea I'll cast my comments into an answer.

*... how to translate a verb turned into a noun?*: take the present participle of the verb and add -e/-er/-en depending on case, gender and article:

> Verb *scheiden* >> participle *scheidend* >> noun *der/die Scheidende*
>   (sg.), *die Scheidenden* (pl.)

"You all, the Departing, give up all hope!" = *Ihr, die Scheidenden - gebt alle Hoffnung auf!*

Or use a verb as in *Ihr, die ihr fortgeht/von uns geht/uns verlasst...*, see comments above.

You'll frequently find participles turned into nouns as titles of works of art:

> Die Stehende von xyz. = Standing woman by xyz.

Note that in English, you'll have to add a noun to make clear who is standing here. In German, this is expressed by the article: *der Stehende / die Stehende / die Stehenden*.